# Need to create registry key with multiple values

Tags: windows

I am trying to create a registry. But I cannot able to add only one value only. Herewith I had enclosed the screenshots

[File need to create](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wf9I1.png)

[Registry file that I am trying to create](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2yney.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has only one value.

The value is 3.

3 means "enabled".

https://i.stack.imgur.com/YWpjS.png